# redis sort by multi fields

Tags: sorting, redis

It's easy to use sql to query with multi sort fields.For example:

```
select * from user order by score desc,name desc
```

with two fields sort(score,name).

how should do this in redis?

Answer (score 2):

Use sorted set of redis which is sorted by score. You have to prepare score according to your needs.

```
finalScore = score*MAX_NAME_VALUE + getIntRepresentation(name) 
//MAX_NAME_VALUE is the maximum value returned by getIntRepresentation() method
```

and then use

```
 zadd myset finalScore value
```

and the just use

```
zrevrange myset 0 10
```